# webview in scrollview windows phone 8.1

Tags: webview, windows-phone-8.1, scrollview

I have a webview in a scrollview in a Windows phone 8.1 application, I set the height of the webview to fit its content and disabled the scrollview in the webview, but when I scroll the webview the scrollview is not scrolling.

the same code work for Windows store 8.1.

Comment: You may want to check my answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705584/windows-phone-8-1-handle-webview-vertical-scroll-by-outer-scrollviewer-element/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<WebView Source="http://www.example.com/"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" />
```